# Nested Loop PHP MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the results from my query but I don't seem to get the nested loop work. Here is the image that may help to explain what I am trying to do. 
[image]

Esentially this is what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Following is where I am having difficulty

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT CandidateName, CandidateVotes, Party, MainRaceName, RaceName, win
FROM candidates
WHERE RaceID = $RaceID";

  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  for($i=0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++){
     ?>
        <!-- FOR LOOP 1 SHOW MainRaceName  -->
      {
        <h1><?php echo $row['MainRaceName']; ?></h1>


                    <!-- FOR LOOP 2 SHOW RaceName  -->
              {
              <h1><?php echo $row['RaceName']; ?></h1>


                    {

                     <h1><?php echo $row['CandidateName']; ?></h1>
                     <h1><?php echo $row['CandidateVote']; ?></h1>
                     .
                     .

                    }

               }
     }      



  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

You might have an easy solution and I appreciate your time and help. 
I am working on changing the code to PDO and I am aware of the SQL injection related risks.

Comment: There are no nested loops in your code. What is it supposed to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Why are you troubleshooting that code if you're not going to use it? All `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated for years, with alternatives available for more than a decade. Move to PDO.

Comment: Barmar I know. That is where I need help. I added another image to show where I need help. There may be other solutions instead of nested statement. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are querying for `RaceName` only then this should do it.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT CandidateName, CandidateVotes, Party, MainRaceName, RaceName, win
FROM candidates
WHERE RaceID = $RaceID";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result), $i++) {
    // Print out main race name and race name on first iteration only
    if ($i === 0) {
?>
        <h1><?php echo $row['MainRaceName'] ?></h1>
        <h1><?php echo $row['RaceName'] ?></h1>
<?php
    }
?>
    <p><?php echo $row['CandidateName'] ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row['CandidateVotes'] ?></p>
<?php
}
?>
```

If you are querying for `MainRaceName` and you need to print out all races under main race, I would group race names together with candidates and get total candidate votes for specific race name like this.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT CandidateName, CandidateVotes, Party, MainRaceName, RaceName, win
FROM candidates
WHERE RaceID = $RaceID";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$grouped_result = array();
$total_votes = 0;
$main_race = '';

for ($i = 0; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result), $i++) {
    // If it is first iteration, set the current race name to race name in row
    // and save main race name
    if ($i === 0) {
        $main_race = $row['MainRaceName'];
        $cur_race = $row['RaceName'];
    }
    // If current race name is different than race name in row we reset
    // total count of votes, since we need to have sum of votes grouped by race name
    if ($cur_race != $row['RaceName']) {
        $total_votes = 0;
    }    
    // Populate grouped array
    $grouped_result[$row['RaceName']]['candidates'][] = array(
        'name'  => $row['CandidateName'],
        'votes' => $row['CandidateVote']
    );
    $grouped_result[$row['RaceName']]['total_votes'] = $total_votes + $row['CandidateVotes'];;
}
```

From your pictures `$grouped_result` would give you a nested array something like this.

```
array(
   'President' => array(
       'candidates' => array(
           0 => array(
               'name'  => 'Mr. X',
               'votes' => 429
           ),
           1 => array(
               'name'  => 'Ms. Y',
               'votes' => 43
           ),
                  .
                  .
                  .
       ),
       'total_votes' => 5247
   ),
   'US House of ...' => array(
       'candidates' => array(
           0 => array(
               'name'  => 'whatever_his_name_is',
               'votes' => 3693 
           )        
        )
       'total_votes' => 3693
   )
)
```

Now you can go and print out the html.

```
<h1><?php echo $main_race ?></h1>
<?php 
    // loop through all races
    foreach ($grouped_result as $racename => $data): 
?>
        <h1><?php echo $racename ?></h1>
    <?php 
        // loop through all candidates in this race
        foreach ($data['candidates'] as $candidate): 
    ?>
            <p><?php echo $candidate['name'] ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $candidate['votes'] ?></p>
            <!-- Calculate vote percentages -->
            <p><?php echo ($candidate['votes'] / $data['total_votes']) * 100 ?> %</p>
    <?php 
        endforeach; 
    ?>
        <h1>Total votes: <?php echo $data['total_votes'] ?></h1>
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```

Now you can style all that, put into table, whatever...

Comment: The second part of the `for` loop doesn't have to be the number of times. It can be any expression that can be used as a condition. Assigning to `$row` works just as well in `for` as it does in `while`.

Comment: @Barmar I never used `for` loops that way, I guess you learn something new everyday.

Comment: Your code is more idiomatic, since he's not using the `$i` variable for anything.

Comment: Well TheDrot thank you for your help but I don't think I explained the question correctly.

Comment: I added another image to explain what exactly i am trying to accomplish.